# Disable the default logging of Akka ActorSystem

Tags: scala, logging, akka

I need an `ActorSystem` that does not log anything. Trying HTTP things with spray, I'm so stupid that I can't help copying and pasting their example code [here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-client/). As you would see they're using `ActorSystem`, whose default config messes up the stdout with a whole bunch of INFO. So how do you make an `ActorSystem` that fits to my need? If it could be done without any external XML or config files, I would love the way. Thank you! :)

Comment: "I'm so stupid that I can't help copying and pasting their example code". You aren't stupid. Reading and modifying code that others have written is a great way to learn. If you feel "stupid" copying code, why not retype it? I tend to get a better feel for what's going on when I type something as opposed to copying it. Don't say you are stupid because you don't magically know something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import spray.http._
import spray.client.pipelining._
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.typesafe.config._

val config = ConfigFactory.load()
     .withValue("akka.loglevel", ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef("OFF"))
     .withValue("akka.stdout-loglevel", ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef("OFF"))
implicit val system = ActorSystem("AlwaysNameYourSystem", config)
import system.dispatcher // execution context for futures
// ... here goes the rest of example code
```

**What's done here**

- Manually created an instance of [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#using-the-library)
- Set log level values to highest level possible.
- Constructed `ActorSystem` with explicit configuraion ([docs here](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.5/?_ga=1.129424458.753487088.1403613881#akka.actor.ActorSystem$)).

At this point you shouldn't see any messages during system startup and any spray notification

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) I always wonder if those config things can be type safe or it's impossible

Answer (score 0):

This configuration in **.conf** worked for me as well

```
akka {
  # Log the complete configuration at INFO level when the actor system is started.
  # This is useful when you are uncertain of what configuration is used.
  log-config-on-start = off
}
```

Documentation [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/logging.html#auxiliary-logging-options)